# Filtering relative dates to get the last 2 shifts moving

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to filter my Power BI Report to get the last 2 shifts moving. I have a date dimension table, a time dimension table and a shift dimension table.

My shift dimension table is composed of 2 rows, the first one is the Day Shift (from 6h AM to 5:59 PM) and the Night Shift (from 6h PM to 5:59 AM). The reference for the day shift is 1 and for the night shift is 2.

I have a fact table showcasing results for each day related to each shift. What I am trying to do, is always showcasing the last 2 shifts completed, for example we are October 18th at 8h30 AM, then I wanna see the last 2 shifts completed which is the night shift (from October 17th 6h PM to October 18th 5:59 AM) and the day shift (from October 17th 6h AM to 5:59 PM).

I would also want to go back in time, so for example filter my data so I can go back in time.

How can I do this? Do I need to have a Shift Dimension with all my shift and dates instead of a 2 row dimension table only displaying the day vs. night shift?

This is what my Shift Table look like :
[image]

This is what my Date Table look like :

[image]

This is what my time table looks like :

[image]

This is what my fact table look like :

[image]

So what I am trying to do is filter my data in sort to have the last 2 shifts available and completed.

This is what my first attempt looked like :

At first, I added the column date in my fact table to have the full date :

[image]

Second, I created a new column, using DAX in my FactTable to indicate if, with true or false, the row was in the last 2 days available :

[image]

This is what it looks like in the visual form :

[image]

What I am trying to do is filter depending the last 2 shifts, not days and between the hours related to the shifts in sort to always have the last two shift available. I don't know if it's possible with the shift table only having 2 rows or is it just possible with a dimshift that contains all the shifts with the dates and hours ?

What I want to display is the sum of the quantity for the last 2 available shifts, so for this example that will be for September 27th Night Shift (from 6h PM to 5:59:59 AM) and for September 28th day shift (6h AM to 5:59:59 PM). When I click on true, I would like to be able to filter the 2 lasts shifts and when I don't filter the data, I should be able to go back in time and look at historical data

Comment: Please share your fact table and expected dimensional table format in your mind. You don't have to share actual data, just fake data with similar format. Show us what efforts you put in solving the problem. Then we can help you pleasantly. To answer shortly, It is much more efficient to have a Date Dimension table involving all shifts if you want to go back to previous dates or track the trend.

Comment: Could you clarify what results you are looking for?  i.e. do you want the sum of hours for the last two shifts?  Could you also show us what you have tried?  It will be much easier to answer the question referencing the tables and columns in your model.

Comment: Hi, I just updated my problem if you wanna have more informations about the context @OzanSen

Comment: Hi, I just updated my problem if you wanna have more informations about the context @MarkWojciechowicz

Comment: Hi @Alexandra. Thank you for updating your post. I will take some time to examine it and try to offer some solution if I can! Be well!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve it in a different way, Please check my reasoning, see if It is what you want.

First Here is the data model I used, according to your shared sets:

[image: Model View]

Then I started by creating a calculated table using this DAX Code:

```
Calc_Table = 
VAR TblSummary = SUMMARIZE(YourFactTable, 'Date'[Date], 'Time'[HH:mm:ss], Shift[RefShift])
VAR RankColumnAdded = ADDCOLUMNS(TblSummary,
"Rank",
    RANKX(TblSummary,[Date] + [HH:mm:ss]))
VAR QuantityColumnAdded = ADDCOLUMNS(
    RankColumnAdded,
    "QuantityAmount",CALCULATE(SUM(YourFactTable[Quantity])))
VAR Filter_Last2 = FILTER(QuantityColumnAdded, [Rank] IN {1,2})
RETURN
Filter_Last2
```

My calculate table looks like this:

[image: Calculated Table View]

Then you can use it in a table visual by dragging and dropping fields on calculated tables formed, result is this:

[image: This is the result]

Note: You don't need to create 'Last 2 days' column in your solution; because RANK() function sorts it according to Date + Time values, and takes the last 2.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Actually it's not the result I am looking for. What I showed is just an example of the data I have in my fact table, but each shift contains multiple rows, not just 2 so that means I need all quantities in the last 2 shifts (day and night) so that means a lot of rows not just 2 for each shift so I cannot take the last 2 based on the hours. Also, what I would like to do is filter the data in the report, I already have a measure which calculates my quantities and that's what I use to display the data.

Comment: What I would like is filtering the data in order to have the last 2 available shifts (from 6h AM to 5:59:59 PM for day and from 6h PM to 5:59:59 AM for the night shift). I don't wanna create another table I think I prefer if the data stay in the fact table or if we create additional measures. Do you think there's a way to do it ?